# Render sentence with values in dict python

Tags: python, dictionary, match, render

Say I have a sentence to fill

```
sentence_to_fill = "I have 4 {{fruit}}"
```

And I have dictionary like this

```
my_dict = { "fruit": ["apple", "banana", "pear"] }
```

I would like to see something like this given input:

```
 Input: "I have 4 apple"
 Output: True, "apple"
```

And only returns True with fruit if matches one of the values in the dict in python.

What would be the easiest and the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over the format of `sentence_to_fill` and can make it `I have 4 {fruit}` instead, you can take advantage of `**kwargs` and `format()` to do this instead or regular expressions:

```
def test_fruit_sentence(sentence):
    template = "I have 4 {fruit}"
    valid_values = {"fruit": ["apple", "banana", "pear"]}
    for key, values in valid_values.items():
        for value in values:
            generated_sentence = template.format(**{key: value})
            if generated_sentence == sentence:
                return True, value
    return False, None

result = test_fruit_sentence("I have 4 apple")
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression to match.

```
import re
input = 'I have 4 apple'
my_dict = { "fruit": ["apple", "banana", "pear"] }
m = re.match(r'I have 4 (%s)' % '|'.join(my_dict['fruit']), input)
print(True if m else False, m.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search using regex and use Python's `in` keyword to check membership in a dictionary.
The re.search will search for the {{...}} pattern, group(1) selects the text within the curly brackets, and then you can check for membership in the supplied dictionary.

```
import re
def test_fruit(my_dict, sentence):
    return re.search(r'{{(.*)}}', sentence).group(1) in my_dict['fruit']
```